# Deploying with capistrano 3 throws can't convert Rake::Task to String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano3, rvm-capistrano

I'm trying to do my first deploy with capistrano3. 
I'm really new on this and I'm stuck here: running

```
 cap deploy:setup
```

I get this error

```
cap aborted!
TypeError: can't convert Rake::Task to String
```

In my deploy.rb file I have this

```
require 'capistrano/setup' 
require 'capistrano/deploy'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rvm'
require 'capistrano/rails/assets'
require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'
require "whenever/capistrano"
Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.cap').each { |r| import r }
```

after a lot of googling I've found something about rvm1-capistrano3;
but if I change this line

```
require 'capistrano/rvm'
```

with this one

```
require 'rvm1/capistrano3'
```

But nothing changes. I still receive that error.
Of course I've tried every kind of reinstallation or update but I can't get out of this.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an issue with the newest release of rake (10.2.1). Specifying its version to '10.1.1' worked for me:

```
# In your gemfile
gem 'rake', '10.1.1'
```

Then run `bundle update rake`, commit all files (including Gemfle.lock), push to origin and redeploy.